# Connect notebook to 4k monitor at 60hz

Tags: laptop, usb, display, connection, 4k-resolution

I can't find a way to connect my laptop ([Notebook HP - 15ay114nl](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05367203)) to my 4k monitor ([Samsung U28E590D Monitor 4K Ultra HD, 28", UHD, 3840 x 2160, 60 Hz, 1 ms, 2 HDMI, Display Port](http://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/uhd-and-wqhd/samsung-uhd-28-monitor-with-high-glossy-black-finish-lu28e590ds-za/)) at 60Hz.

Currently I've connected the two at 30hz via HDMI.

I've done quite a bit of research online to find a solution but apparently a 3.1 type C USB port is needed: I've found out my PC has a 3.1 but it's not type C (quite confusing).

How can I solve this?

Comment: This HP model doesn't seem to have DP. How do you connect then?

Comment: @AliChen You're right! I got confused with another PC I own. I connect this one to the monitor via HDMI at the moment but I'm looking for 60hz. Question edited.

Comment: The Samsung monitor does support HDMI 2.0, with 4k@60 capability. However, I found no indication where M440 can support 4k at 60Hz over HDMI. The chipset does support this mode over DP, but the DP is not implemented in your NB. So it looks like you are out of luck..

Comment: @AliChen Can I use the USB port to connect my laptop to the monitor?

Comment: Maybe, via some USB3.0 docking station, which contains a high-end DP chip. Maybe there are USB 3.0 to DP adapters. Search is your friend. Keywords are HDMI 2.0 and DP 1.4.

Comment: @AliChen Could you please clarify? I'm not an expert and I'd like to be sure to have comprehended properly before buying anything. Your suggestions are: 1) Find a USB 3.0 to DP adaptor (then I could simply connect via DP and get 4k@60?) 2) Why do you mention HDMI 2.0? Should I search for HDMI 2.0 to DP also?

Comment: What about using this: https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-USB-DisplayPort-Cable-Monitor/dp/B01E9RTEI8 in conjunction with https://www.amazon.com/Lemeng-USB3-0-Connector-Converter-Adapter/dp/B01ABTHI7C/ref=sr_1_15?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1503423717&sr=1-15&keywords=usb+type+c+to+usb+3.0+adapter ? I would then use the adaptor from USB 3.0 to USB 3.1 type C and from that to DP. Seems reasonable? Thanks

Comment: No, these are all simple passive cables. If your PC doesn't have a dedicated DP port (or DP alternate mode on Type-C), passive cables won't help. With USB 3 only, you need one of these adapters based on DisplayLink technology, http://www.displaylink.com/products/usb-adapters

Comment: But these will support 4k@60Hz? For example this one (https://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/usb-3-4k-displayport-adapter~USB32DP4K) has a maximum resolution of 4K x 2K @ 30Hz

Comment: To achieve 4K@60Hz each connected monitor and cable must support the desired resolution and refresh rate.

DisplayPort equipped monitors and DisplayPort cable must support DisplayPort 1.2 specification in order to support 4K@60Hz. While backwards compatible with DisplayPort 1.1 standards, the resolution will be limited to 4K@30Hz if the display or cable does not support DisplayPort 1.2 specifications. http://plugable.com/products/usbc-6950-dp/

Comment: @AliChen Sorry to extend the discussion. I appreciate your efforts to help me. The product you linked has a 3.1 type C USB port, my PC instead doesn't have type C. I just want to make sure if there is a possibility to use 4k@60Hz with my current pc+monitor or not.